# modify liferay url parameters (namespace have to be removed from parameters)

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portal

For e.g. 
If i am in the page:
https://qa-some-server.net/miportal/group/pmas/my-business/accounts/holdings?categoryLevel=3

from one of the jsf portlet, if a link is clicked, it navigates to page a like below with parameters containing namespace :

https: //qa-some-server.net/miportal/group/pmas/my-business/accounts/holdings?_CustodianHoldings_WAR_pmasreportsportlet_categoryLevel=3

_CustodianHoldings_WAR_pmasreportsportlet_ - name space prepends to parameter name categoryLevel

But what i want is - 
https://qa-some-server.net/miportal/group/pmas/my-business/accounts/holdings?categoryLevel=2

How to hack and get this behaviour ?? ... 
(Please no alternate approaches. For my application design, this is the only way.)
Please let me know if this url parameters can be modified through any means. I tried friendly url mapping, no luck. may be i did wrong. or can this be altered using liferay hook or ext plugin ?? if so pls give me some inputs, so that i can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting this parameter categoryLevel=3 in below manner and check?

```
String yourRenderURL = yourRenderURL.toString();
HttpUtil.setParameter(yourRenderURL, categoryLevel, 3);
```

Hope this help !

Comment: i need to provide the link from the page like when a link i clicked. for e.g. i use jsf portlet, if in the bean i form a url and if i set the parameter in bean and if use to tostring to get the url in xhtml page. will it work ??